# Kali - atftpd kali-linux-headless kali-linux-default isn't configure yet

Tags: updates, kali-linux

When I try to upgrade my Kali, I received this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  hydra hydra-gtk libgs9 libnet-libidn-perl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up atftpd (0.7.git20210202-3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/atftpd.config: 3: /etc/default/atftpd: 69: not found
dpkg: error processing package atftpd (--configure):
 installed atftpd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kali-linux-headless:
 kali-linux-headless depends on atftpd; however:
  Package atftpd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kali-linux-headless (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kali-linux-default:
 kali-linux-default depends on kali-linux-headless; however:
  Package kali-linux-headless is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kali-linux-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 atftpd
 kali-linux-headless
 kali-linux-default
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I search how to configure/install this 3 pkgs ( atftpd, kali-linux-headless, and kali-linux-default)
I search for a long time but I didn't found anythings. Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution!

You have to remove and purge the pkgs and install it again like that:

```
sudo apt remove --purge atftpd

sudo apt clean

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt-get install atftpd
```

and update:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.